# pointing node.js app to my ip address and running locally

Tags: node.js, web-hosting, vps

So I have two questions about the topic. I have purchased a VPS with digitalocean.com to host my node.js app and they gave me an example hello world app to start.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
var html = "hello world";
res.end(html);
}).listen(8080, 'localhost');
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8080/');
```

So this code works locally and when I host on the VPS I replace 'localhost' with the IP address of my VPS and it is available on the web when I go to http://IP_Address_of_VPS:8080

My first question: How do I host it live on the web but have it point to my IP address? When I replace 'localhost' with my IP address it does not work when I go to http://my_IP_Address:8080

My second question: 
I made a test app following a node.js tutorial and here is the code

```
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

http.listen(PORT, function(){
console.log('listening on port *:'+PORT);
});
```

Where public is the folder with a simple html page. This app works when I run it locally at http://localhost:8080

Can someone explain how the second app runs locally when I did not specify 'localhost' in the http.listen() function? Also how do I point the second app to run from my IP address if the process is any different from the first?

Comment: "How do I host it live on the web but have it point to my IP address?"  I don't understand this question.  You just said it was working fine when you went to the IP of the VPS directly?  You mean you want your local IP address?

Comment: For your second question... you don't need to specify a bind address.  It will bind to all interfaces.  I'm surprised binding to `localhost` actually works.

Comment: @Brad To your first comment- yeah that's what meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First question

I hope I understood your question right, here is an attempt at an answer :)

Depends a bit on what you mean with 'my ip address'. If it is your public ip adress, you might have to set up port forwarding. Most routers will deny traffic from the outside network (which you are doing when connecting to your own public ip address) to the internal network by default.

If you mean a private ip address (local to the local network) you need to you use your public ip address and set up port fowarding.

When you set up port forwarding to your local machine you might also want to make your private ip address static.

However, I do not recommend using your home computer as a production server. You will need to solve a lot of problems like making your network secure and having low downtime.

## Second question

When no hostname is passed to `http.listen`, the server will accept connections on all adresses. [See documentation for more information](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback).

This works, because when you omit arguments in a function call, they will default to`undefined`. For example, `http.listen(8080)` might appear as `http.listen(8080, undefined, undefined, undefined)`. Inside the function body these will often be substituted with some default value.

The process of making your app available to the rest of the world should not be any different.

Comment: Thanks for the info. About the second question, I haven't tried yet but what if I wanted to host the second app on the VPS? Do I just need to add the IP address of the VPS to the http.listen() function in place of the anonymous function there?

Comment: Depends a bit on the setup, but using http.listen as provided should probably be fine. By not tying your service to their ip adress your app will also be accessible via ipv6 or when you decide to move to a different host. The application is not responsible for setting an public ip address.